# How do I migrate a mysql database from server to localhost?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I want to export the database into my localhost. My database size is very big. It's almost 150GB. I've tried using MySQL workbench. But it's not working. How can I import the database into my localhost?

Comment: Another option is to make a database backup file, then compress it, and then transfer it. Using data-_export_ tools is the worst way to do it because those give you uncompressed SQL `INSERT` statements, or CSV (or JSON...) with redundant metadata everywhere. All you need is a good ol' fashioned binary/page-based backup. The only caveat is that both your on-prem and remote MySQL instances probably need to be running the exact same version (I might be wrong, it's been over a decade since I did MySQL admin).

Answer (score 0):

you can use xtrabackup or mysqlbackup